# Parameter pack causes "uninitialized local variable" in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++

The following code compiles well under gcc and clang, but throws the C4700 "uninitialized local variable 'a' used" error in Visual Studio 2015 and older:

```
template<int T>
class V
{
public:
    int v[T];

    V() = default;
    template<typename ...A>
    V(A... args):
        v{args...}
    {}
};

int main()
{
    V<2> a(2, 2);
    V<2> b = a;
    return 0;
}
```

If I add body to the constructor (by removing the `= default` and adding `{}`) the error goes away. I can' t find anything that mandates this behavior in the spec. Is this a bug in Visual C++ compiler or I am missing something in the spec?

Comment: I tried compiling it with different versions of Visual Studio and I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think VS older than 2015 will support this. Not sure about 2015.  It compiled with 2017 and failed with 2013 (although I expected it to fail with that).